# QGIS Zonal Statistics for polygons is missing results?

Tags: qgis, raster, polygon, zonal-statistics

I am carrying out an analysis using QGIS 2.14.1 where I am dealing with point data that have been randomly displaced by either up to 2 Km or 5 Km. I have generated a buffer of the appropriate radius around each point and now want to obtain mean values for each polygon from a raster layer.

To do this I have used the Zonal Statistics tool but for about 10% of my points no results have been generated even though there is raster data for that location. All the polygons with missing data have a 2 Km radius. The Zonal Statistics tool worked for some of the polygons with a 2 Km radius, just not all. The raster layer I am dealing with has a resolution of 5 X 5 Km.

When I increase the size of the polygon I am able to obtain zonal statistics results, which suggests to me that the size of the polygon may be too small. However, I cannot alter the polygon size because the point can only be within this radius and therefore enlarging the polygon would make the results inaccurate.

I understand that if polygons overlap this can sometimes cause issues. Whilst some of the polygons do overlap, some of them do not. I also tried doing this for one polygon at a time but still did not get results with the ones I tried. I have included an image below where the smaller green polygon is an example of one of the polygons that has missing Zonal Statistics output.

I am aware of multiple other Q&As addressing this type of issue but nothing I have tried has worked so far. The Q&As I have seen are:

- [Missing buffer values when using zonal statistics in ArcGIS Desktop?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/195166/missing-buffer-values-when-using-zonal-statistics-in-arcgis)
- [Zonal Statistics as a Table does not calculate statistics for all features in dataset?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/132653/zonal-statistics-as-a-table-does-not-calculate-statistics-for-all-features-in-th?rq=1)
- [Zonal Statistics As A Table missing Features in Results?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/140016/zonal-statistics-as-a-table-missing-features-in-results?rq=1)
- [Polygons too Small for Zonal Statistics](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/223789/polygons-too-small-for-zonal-statistics)
- [Zonal statistics results in some NULL values in QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/238525/zonal-statistics-results-in-some-null-values)

I do not use Python.

[image: The smaller green polygon is an example of one polygon with missing Zonal Statistics output]

Comment: Welcome to GIS:SE @sha12! Did you ensure the CRS of your layers are consistent? And have you considered testing this on a more recent version of QGIS (as of now 2.18)?

Comment: Hi - thank you for your comment. The CRS of my layers are consistent. I haven't tried upgrading to 2.18 but that is a good suggestion - I will see if that helps.